# Python: get datetime of last hour

Tags: python, datetime, hour

I want to get the date time object for last hour.
Lets say the sys time is "2011-9-28 06:11:30"
I want to get the output as "2011-9-28 05" #{06 - 1 hour}

I used:

```
    lastHourDateTime = date.today() - timedelta(hours = 1)
    print lastHourDateTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

However, my output is not showing the time part at all. where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Date doesn't have the hour - use datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
last_hour_date_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = 1)
print(last_hour_date_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: This is the way I always do it, but I wish I had a 1 function way to write this instead of calling 2 functions and subtracting. I might make a simple library for it.

Comment: Careful: This appears to return unexpected results. `datetime.now()` is [definitely preferred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298332/python3-4-datetime-today-and-datetime-now).

Comment: Warning, you are using `datetime.now()` but datetime is not imported, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 22):

This works for me:

```
import datetime

lastHourDateTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
print(lastHourDateTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H'))

# prints "2011-09-28 12" which is the time one hour ago in Central Europe
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same goal using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.Timedelta('1 hours')
```