# Python3.4 datetime.today() and datetime.now()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.today()
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 30, 23, 17, 6, 937659)
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 30, 23, 17, 14, 378097)
>>>
```

In Python3.4 datetime.today()  and datetime.now()  What's the difference?

Answer (score 4):

According to the document of `datetime.now(tz=None)`:

> Return the current local date and time. If optional argument `tz` is `None` or not specified, this is like `today()`, but, if possible, supplies more precision than can be gotten from going through a `time.time()` timestamp (for example, this may be possible on platforms supplying the C `gettimeofday()` function).
>
> Else `tz` must be an instance of a class `tzinfo` subclass, and the current date and time are converted to `tz`‘s time zone. In this case the result is equivalent to `tz.fromutc(datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=tz))`.

Thus `datetime.now()` supplies more precision if possible.

Comment: Get it, Thank you so much.