# What is the difference between datetime.now() and datetime.today() in Python

Tags: python, datetime

Is there any difference between datetime.today() and datetime.now()?

Using them lately has proved that there is none.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545254/difference-between-system-datetime-now-and-system-datetime-today

Comment: `datetime.today` gives you non timezone aware time. `datetime.now` acccepts timezone info as argument and can provide tz spcific time and date

Comment: What platform are you talking about? The example code could be from at least a dozen languages.

Comment: I was talking about Python. Sorry for forgetting to mention the language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3.4 datetime.today() and datetime.now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298332/python3-4-datetime-today-and-datetime-now)

Comment: @NicolòGasparini Absolutely! Since then I have learned a lot about DateTime as I went from python 2.7 to 3.9.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**DateTime.Today** only gives today's date and default time as 12:00:00.

DateTime.Today : 1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM.

**DateTime.Now** gives current time of running thread with today's date. (Date and Time of the computer where code is running)

DateTime.Now : 1/1/2018 8:49:52 AM.

Comment: This is incorrect - the time for both reflects the current time - not 12:00:00 AM for DateTime.Today