# How can I filter a pandas data frame based on a datetime column between current time and 10 hours ago?

Tags: pandas, datetime, filter, time, compare

I have a pandas DataFrame which includes a datetime column and I want to filter the data frame between the current hour and 10 hours ago. I have tried different ways to do it but still I cannot handle it. Because when I want to use pandas, the column type is Series and I can't use timedelta to compare them. If I use a for loop to compare the column as a string to my time interval, it is not efficient.

The table is like this:

[image]

And I want to filter the 'dateTime' column between current time and 10 hours ago, then filter based on 'weeks' > 80.

I have tried these codes as well But they have not worked:

```
filter_criteria = main_table['dateTime'].sub(today).abs().apply(lambda x: x.hours <= 10)
main_table.loc[filter_criteria]
```

This returns an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Similarly this code has the same problem:

```
main_table.loc[main_table['dateTime'] >= (datetime.datetime.today() - pd.DateOffset(hours=10))]
```

And:

```
main_table[(pd.to_datetime('today') - main_table['dateTime'] ).dt.hours.le(10)]
```

In all of the code above main_table is the name of my data frame.
How can I filter them?

Comment: have you converted your datetime column to actual datetime object? you can do it using `to_datetime()`

Comment: what should I import to do it?
  
`
import datetime
check = datetime.to_datetime(main_table['dateTime'])
print(check - - timedelta(hours=10))
`

Comment: it is one of the pandas methods. you can see how it is done in here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-the-column-type-from-string-to-datetime-format-in-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: I have tried this:  
check = pd.to_datetime(main_table['dateTime'])  
But I still do not know how I can filter the dataframe between two hours!

Comment: I have print the type of check to be sure about the results, unfortunately it is still pandas series: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure that your datatype in datetime column is correct. you can check it by using:

```
main_table.info()
```

If it is not datetime (i.e, object) convert it:

```
# use proper formatting if this line does not work
main_table['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(main_table['dateTime'])
```

Then you need to find the datetime object of ten hour before current time ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582333/python-get-datetime-of-last-hour)):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date_time_ten_before = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = 10)
```

All it remains is to filter the column:

```
main_table_10 = main_table[main_table['dateTime'] >= date_time_ten_before]
```